# Wordpress how to set default values for widgets?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im trying to make my own widget. But i found out that this is not so easy. I'm trying to set default values but i have no idea how to do this.

Yes, i have Googled a lot. I'm almost trying for 1 week to get my own options page and custom widgets, but im not succeeding.

so back to my question, this is my code now:

```
class Superdeal_Widget extends WP_Widget {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(
        'Superdeal-widget',
        'Superdeal Widget',
        array(
            'description' => 'Superdeal widget'
        ),
        array (
            'width' => 400,
            'height' => 350
        )
    );
}  

public function widget( $args, $instance )
  {
    // basic output just for this example
    echo '<p><a href="'.$instance['url'].'">'.$instance['titel'].'&nbsp;'.$instance['superdeal'].'</a></p>';

  }

  public function form( $instance )
  {
    // removed the for loop, you can create new instances of the widget instead
    ?>
     <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('titel'); ?>">Titel</label><br />
      <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('titel'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('titel'); ?>-title" value="<?php echo $instance['titel']; ?>" class="widefat" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('url'); ?>">Url</label><br />
      <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('url'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('url'); ?>-url" value="<?php echo $instance['url']; ?>" class="widefat" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('superdeal'); ?>">Superdeal tekst</label><br />
      <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('superdeal'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('superdeal'); ?>-title" value="<?php echo $instance['superdeal']; ?>" class="widefat" />
    </p>
    <?php
  }


} 
// end class

// init the widget
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("Superdeal_Widget");') );
```

PS: if you know a good tutorial which shows how to make you own options page / declare properties / makeing custom widgets, i would love to hear from you. Because all the tutorials i have followd are old, obscure or way too complicated.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Sorry to inform, but you've been following the wrong tutorials, [this one](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/05/26/the-complete-guide-to-creating-widgets-in-wordpress-28) is almost 5 years old and still stands ;) Well, Justin Tadlock is a heavy weight developer. Also, instead of Google, research first at [wordpress.se]. Oh, lots of good stuff at WPTuts+ too.

Comment: Hello brasofilo, I know the tuts i've followed were crap :( i will try this one tanks for your reaction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should help you → [widget tutorial](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-create-wordpress-widgets/)

Note on this line from `form()` function:

```php
$instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => 'DEFAULT_VALUE_HERE' ) );
```

You can add several instances like:

```php
array( 'title' => 'DEFAULT_VALUE_HERE', 'name' => 'DEFAULT_VALUE_HERE')
```

Hope this would help you going.

Comment: Kindly accept this as an answer if this solves your problem. Thanks!